# Collect Senders Email Addresses From Specific Folder At Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

as my title mentioned I am searching for a solution to get all email addresses that I have received from people and saved inside a certain folder in my Thunderbird.

I need them for marketing purposes, because those email addresses belong to people I have done business with.

Thanks for help.

Best
RS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Message Filter in order to organize your messages.

Read this article: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/organize-your-messages-using-filters

**Updated:**

Select all the emails in that folder and saved them on a directory as a `*.eml` file format.

In the terminal: `cd /path/to/eml/directory` Then run:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} \; | nl | grep "From" | grep -o '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' | uniq -ui | sort > collected-emails.csv
```

Now, All the collected emails will be saved in **collected-emails.csv**

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not see where I have written that I want to filter or organize my emails. I want to get all senders email addresses from those emails that are saved inside a specific thunderbird folder.

Comment: @RudolfSchmidt I am sorry for miss understanding the question! 

I am running thunderbird on a Linux Mint. To export all sender email addresses in a folder. I select all the emails in that folder and saved them on a directory as a *.eml file format.


In the terminal `cd /path/to/eml/directory`

Then run `find . -type f -exec cat {} \; | nl | grep  "From" | grep -o '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' | uniq -ui | sort > collected-emails.csv` command to export all email addresses

All the collected emails will be saved in **collected-emails.csv**

Hope this will help you

Comment: a great solution, thanks for that!

Comment: and the easiest way to find and navigate to a directory is to type mc and click down to it